# SQL Designating a value of a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this script to find the `service_code`(s) that match with the `ada_code` from my services table and then finding the transactions that have those `service_code`s as the `ada_code` is not in the `transactions` table

```
WITH dentures AS (
SELECT service_code
FROM services
WHERE (ada_code='D5110' OR ada_code='D5120' OR ada_code='D5130' OR ada_code='D5140' OR ada_code='REMAU' OR ada_code='REAML' OR ada_code='REMAK'))

SELECT t.clinic, COUNT(DISTINCT t.tran_num) AS quantity, d.service_code, SUM(t.amount) AS total, p.fiscal_year, p.period_id
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN dentures d
ON(t.service_code=d.service_code)
CROSS JOIN period p
WHERE (t.time_ran BETWEEN p.period_start AND p.period_end)
AND status='A'
AND impacts='P'
GROUP BY t.clinic, d.service_code, p.fiscal_year, p.period_id
```

The script works find as is, however I need to separate into two different groups. Group A (All service codes from D5110, D5120, D5130, D5140) and Group B which are the left overs. Is there a way to essentially look at the `service_code` from services that use those `ada_code`s and predetermine them as a group prior? Between the four `ada_code`s in Group A there's roughly 10 for each and I have 35 different unique locations that use them as well that need to be kept separate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping by service code, simply group by a case statement like

```
CASE WHEN servicecode IN (group a codes) "Group A"
       ELSE  servicecode --or "Group B", I'm not sure which you want
END
```